# does not let me use f or f1 as a command for the discord bot

Tags: python, discord

Im trying to use specifically "f1" as the command to pass to the discord bot but I end up getting the error

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "f1" is not found
```

It's weird, since it wasnt complaining when I used hello instead, any reason?

```
import os
import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from discord.ext import commands
import requests

def get_emote(args):
    return "hello"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="$")
load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv("DISCORD_TOKEN")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))

@bot.command()
async def test(ctx,args):
    await ctx.send(get_emote(args))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined a command for "f1", Hence the error.